# Autocomplete prediction with typehead.js does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

So I want to use typehead.js to have an autocomplete field (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    var result;


        var result = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.Domain.domain); },
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          limit: 10,
          prefetch: {
            url: 'data.json'
          }
        });


    result.initialize();

    $('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      name: 'twitter-oss',
      displayKey: 'Domain.domain',
      source: result.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
          '<p class="repo-language">Class {{Domain.class}}</p>',
          '<p class="repo-name"><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{Domain.domain}}" alt=""> {{Domain.domain}}</p>',
          '<p class="repo-description">{{Domain.company}}</p>'
        ].join(''))
      }
    });


    });
```

This is my data source :

```
[
   {
      "Domain":{
         "domain":"duckduckgo.com",
         "company":"DuckDuckGo, Inc.",
         "category":"0"
      }
   },
   {
      "Domain":{
         "domain":"twitter.com",
         "company":"Twitter, Inc.",
         "category":"0"
      }
   },
   {
      "Domain":{
         "domain":"apple.com",
         "company":"Apple, Inc.",
         "category":"0"
      }
   }
]
```

It seems that the dropdown menu works fine, but the input field does not have the prediction displaying (I mean it you start typing "Twi" it does not display in grey "tter" ).

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: did you included the css file?

Comment: This is the CSS file I use: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/css/examples.css

Comment: compare your <input class="typeahead tt-hint" /> to the typeahead.js example in, I think your css override the tt-hint

Comment: There is no other css, and the classes are exactly the same. I don't get it.

Comment: right click the element look in chrome devtool right side style, look at the list, are they the same.

Comment: Yes : <input class="typeahead tt-hint" type="text" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-size: auto; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat repeat;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display key is incorrect. typeahead.js will not parse your key and know that it needs to access a nested object. Instead, in order to achieve the functionality you want, do the following:

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  // ...
  displayKey: function(o) { return o.Domain.domain; }
  // ...
});
```